# Coloring Jquery Time Picker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I have a source code of jquery time picker like this:

```
$("#app_time").timePicker({
    show24Hours: true,
    separator: ':',
    startTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0),
    endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 23, 45, 0),
    step: 15
});
```

I want to give diferent color for time in this list.
example: color of 13:00 is red and 14:00 is green.
Is ther any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ui-timepicker-list li:contains("13:00")').css("color","red");
$('.ui-timepicker-list li:contains("14:00")').css("color","green");
```